# Android 10 / API 29 Kotlin - download video to sub directory in pictures

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager

I'm using this code to download videos:

```
val path = "Pictures/Appname"
val fileName = "example.mp4"
    
val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(fileURL))
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path, fileName)
```

But it works only in API < 29

From API 29 I can only download it into `Pictures` directory by doing:

```
.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, fileName)
```

even though the subfolder `Appname` exists in it.

What's the problem here?

I also tried those from the answers of other questions about this and none of them work:

```
.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path, fileName)
.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this@DownloadFile, path, fileName)
.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(File(path, fileName)))
```

I would also accept a solutions without DownloadManager as long as it downloads the video to `Pictures/Appname` like I've seen other apps doing it also in API >= 29

Comment: You did not tell the value for fileName. Please put it also hardcoded in your post.

Comment: Put that subdir with the file name "appName/fileName".

Comment: Yessss this worked but with slash starting: "/appName/fileName" thanks!! Please answer this and I'll accept

Comment: You deleted your answer??

Comment: No, a moderator,   Jean-François Fabre,   never seen him before, did. Some dont like referring to comments. I reposted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Downloadmanager does not need rights to store to external storage.

The answer  to create a subdir is in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "/appName/" + fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you requested access to the directory you want to download to. Since Android 10 and higher is using scoped-storage by default (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes). The idea behind is that an App can only store data into `/Android/data/com.app.package.name/...` or it needs to ask the user explicitly. The user then selects the folder where the app is allowed access (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage). This means that there will be a user-facing directory picker.

Example which will ask the user to select a folder where to store a file:

```kotlin
val action = Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT
val intent = Intent(action)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        .setType("mime/type") // Change this
        .also { it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, filename) } // Optional: proposed file name
startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE)
```

After the user selects a folder:

```kotlin
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) when (requestCode) {
        YOUR_REQUEST_CODE -> {
            val uri = data?.data
            // here you have the permission to write
            // into the file represented by the uri
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This info has nothing to do with DownloadManager. The DownloadMamager does not need these rights. It can do without.

Comment: Even worse: for Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT you dont need any rights.